# ssis - merge join alternative

Tags: performance, join, ssis, merge

I have a table T1 in database D1 and table T2 in database D2. From T2 I need only those records whose primary keys are listed in T1.
The only way that I know so far is to use Merge Join (Inner Join). Since T2 contains much more records than T1 Merge Join would eliminate all records from T2 that don't exist in T1. Since this method is very slow is there any other method to do this task?

Thanks,

Ilija

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason the [Lookup Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) won't work?

Comment: hmmm... I will definitely try this one too. Thanks!

Comment: Since it sounds like the lookup table will be rather large, you will want to investigate the advanced options and change the lookup type from full to partial or no cache. Otherwise, the package will take a very long time to start as it's locally caching that data. 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Are D1 and D2 both on the same SQL Server instance? If so, the query is trivially easy to write:

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM D2.schema2.T2 t2
JOIN D1.schema1.T1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

(Obviously, you'd have to substitute the real names of the primary key column(s) in the join, as well as the schemas that T1 and T2 live under.)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make your data flow source be a query with the join rather than be a table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your explanation, could you be more specific? Please note that I have two different data sources and join two tables from these 2 dbs.